# How to skip the install of one submodule in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a maven project in which there are many sub modules.
I need to use "mvn clean install" to install it to my local repository, but some of the sub modules I don't want to install them at all. If I run "mvn clean install" on the parent project, all the submodules will be installed as well.

How to skip the install of one sub module？

Comment: Why would you like to skip the installation of a module?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate `profile` to build only particular modules. Others will be excluded. Please, see the example below:

```
    <modules>
        <module>module-1</module>
        <module>module-2</module>  
    ...
    </modules>


<profiles>
     <profile>
         <id>specific-build-name</id>
         <modules>
             <module>module-1</module>
             <module>module-2</module>
             ...
             <module>module-with-tests</module>
         </modules> 
     </profile>
</profiles>

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try

Comment: This is the most suitable solution when you need only several modules. Profiles are designed for such type of tasks too. Happy coding ;)

Comment: This one partly solved my problem. I want to package them all, while install only those I needed. This solution will not only affect install but packaging as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your subModule is under different directory as subdirName,

Add exclude of 'subdirName' to maven-jar-plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/subdirName/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is a sub module not a sub folder. I want to exclude all the files in the sub project, and don't want to generate the jar file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Maven 2.4, you can add the following plugin configuration to the submodule whose installation you want to skip:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```